# desktop file in ubuntu does not execute command

Tags: .desktop

I just installed tor, privoxy and proxychains on Ubuntu 13.10, but they are not experiencing any problems. My problem is based on a .desktop file I created as I think it actually doesn't work properly. The content of that file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Switch IP address
Icon=/usr/desktop/icons/switchip.png
Exec=service tor restart
```

As command `service tor restart` is used to obtain new fake IP address, but when I run it from a terminal, it works. When I click on icon on launcher (which is .desktop file above) it does not take any effect. What I missed or did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Switch IP address
Icon=/usr/desktop/icons/switchip.png
Exec=pkexec service tor restart
```

`service` needs to run as root, using `pkexec`.

Comment: yes, i forgot i must run it as admin... i recently came from kali where you login as root, and forget about sudo command... also, i think this is best way is, as with sudo i must keep terminal=true, and gksudo requires installation. thanks.

Comment: @black_hat_cat, would you accept this answer as it did solve the problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Services need root privileges to run. Try to change:

```
Exec=service tor restart
```

To:

```
Exec=gksu service tor restart
```

Or:

```
Exec=sudo service tor restart
```

Also, this will restart the service. Some services refuse to restart if they're not already running, try to use start instead of restart.

Comment: This will require `Terminal=true`, otherwise `sudo` will be unable to get the password input. `gksu` needs to be installed first (`sudo apt-get install gksu`).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
Terminal=false
```

to

```
Terminal=true
```

and see if it does execute properly. (remember to mark your .desktop file as executable)

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: another thing... does this command work when u use it manually in terminal?